# getExternalFilesDirs returns only one storage on emulator

Tags: android-sdcard

I'd like to write data on both internal memory and sdcard.I have following function:

```
public static void init(Context c){
    File[] roots=c.getExternalFilesDirs(null);
    primaryExternalStorage=roots[0];
    if(roots.length>1)
        secondaryExternalStorage = roots[1];
}
```

This works fine on real device but on emulator `getExternalFilesDirs` returns only one path:
`/storage/sdcard/Android/data/my.app.id/files`
I'm able to move app to sdcard/external memory.
Also there is `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permision in the manifest.
I'm testing on android 5.0(api level 21) emulator

Comment: I tried this and the only way I could make it work was to have two DB I am guessing here but in my experiment when the SD CARD was ejected Android would write to INTERNAL and if SD CARD was in and I did any type of PATH setting to create the DB When I set the PATH to Internal it would ignore the path to EXTERNAL